# Object not being stringfyed and parsed back in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

I am making a web app:frontend in Angular and backend in Rails.
In my frontend, I am saving a variable to `localStorage` and trying to retrieve back later.

Here is a variable I'm saving:

```
var application = {
                "id": 7,
                "visa_type": "string"
        }
```

Then I save this variable to localStorage,

```
localStorage.setItem("key", application);
```

After saving, I return this value, `localStorage.application`, and I get  `"[object Object]"`

so I tried to parse `localStorage.application` but it says

> JSON.Parse,'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

How can I successfully return my object??

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(application));`

Comment: Local storage is a key-value pair storage, where both are string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so basically you can do all of this automatically with angular's cacheProvider, without writing any additional logic.

In your $http request just add cache:true, then when your code logic calls the resource again it will avoid hitting the server and serve the cached results instead.

```
$http({ url : url, cache : true }).then(function(rs){});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to stringify it like below

```
localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(application));
```